# Implied (hidden) parent state in UI-Router

Tags: angular-ui-router

Suppose I have the following nested UI-Router route:

```
/parent/{parentId}/child/{childId}
```

parent:child in my case is a one:many relation, therefore **any valid `childId` implies a specific `parentId`**. I'd like to maintain the nested state in my application, keeping access to parent `resolve` dependencies without reloading between sibling children; but instead **represent the above with the terser URL**:

```
/child/{childId}
```

Ideally, I'd like UI-Router to do as much of the lifting as possible, and only write the action to recover just the parent state when it is lost (for example when loading the entire page from a child route URL).

My responsibility could, for instance, be simply handling recovery of the `parentId` state parameter when it is null.

**Is this feasible?**

***edits day 2:*** It seems, according to the docs, that UI-Router is designed to allow obscuring parent routes from the URL using [Absolute Routes](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#absolute-routes-). I can only assume that it is supposed to preserve the parent state normally in this case. So, I tried a quick implementation by including two identical URLs, one an absolute URL that is a child state of the parent, and the other that is an actual root state, which does nothing but resolve the parent parameter, then load a controller to perform a redirect to the actual `parent/child` route. It had lots of problems. I'm trying to determine if I can do the same thing with an abstract state above the parent route. Anyway, suffice to say I haven't solved this yet.